# Дописать, добавить данные в excel .xls файл в Java с помощью Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, xls, apache-poi, append

Нужно срочное правильное решение по дописыванию данных в .xls файл.
Проблема заключается в том, что если использовать

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pString), true);
```

с параметром **true**, то размер файла растёт, но после завершения открываешь и все данные сбрасываются, и наблюдается лишь одна строка.

Если перед этим использовать копирование всей информации в excel файле и добавлять к копированной, при большой нагрузке и размерах файла свыше 30Мбайт начинаются проблемы, очень сильно нагружается жёсткий диск.

```
public synchronized void writeToXLS(List<String> newRow) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(MainFrame.PATH_OF_PROGRAM + "\\" + MainFrame.NAME_OF_NEW_DATABASE);
    String pString = p.toString();

    if (!Files.exists(p)) {
        Files.createFile(p);
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pString));
        workbook.createSheet("Ready");
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
    }

    try{
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File(pString));

        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);


        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Row row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getLastRowNum()+1);
        for (int cellIndex=0; cellIndex< newRow.size(); cellIndex++) {
            try{
                row.createCell(cellIndex).setCellValue(newRow.get(cellIndex));
            }catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        fis.close();

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(pString), true);
        workbook.write(fos);
        workbook.close();
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: я у себя решил данную проблему new FileOutputStream(new File(outputFile)). предварительно все добавляю в workbook, и в конце сохраняю

Comment: @Senior именно так, Я и делаю, в коде выше можете увидеть.Данный метод не подходит из-за того, что постоянно идёт чтение и копирование не нужных данных, а когда файл становится большого размера, происходит беда жёсткий диск грузится, а добавление данных идёт чаще чем ежесекундно.

Answer (score 2):

`append` в конструкторе `FileOutputStream` дописывает байты в конец файла, при этом он не учитывает структуру excel документа. Могу предположить, что запись документа с  таким флагом приводит к формированию файла с некорректным форматом. Если вы хотите, уменьшить нагрузку на диск,предлагаю использовать буферизированную запись и чтение. При этом, можно поиграться с размером буфера.

```
private static synchronized void writeToXLS(List<String> newRow) throws IOException {
    Path p = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
    String fileName = p.toString();

    if (!Files.exists(p)) {
        Files.createFile(p);
        try (BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(fileName)))) {
            Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
            workbook.createSheet("Ready");
            workbook.write(fos);
            workbook.close();
        }
    }

    try (BufferedInputStream fis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(new File(fileName)))) {

        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        Row row = sheet.createRow(rowCount + 1);
        for (int cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < newRow.size(); cellIndex++) {
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellIndex);
            cell.setCellValue(newRow.get(cellIndex));
        }


        try (BufferedOutputStream fio = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName))) {
            workbook.write(fio);
        }
    }
}
```